# Extract text from multiple xpath and assert text - Selenium/Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to find the text in an element and assert whether it matches with my required result.

The thing is, there can be n number of element from 1-100 in the page. So I can't get the xpath of all those elements and then assert the text in it.

The xpath looks like this: (from the first element)

```
(//DIV[@class='issues-list-item clearfix'])[1]
(//DIV[@class='issues-list-item clearfix'])[2]
(//DIV[@class='issues-list-item clearfix'])[3]
(//DIV[@class='issues-list-item clearfix'])[4]
....
(//DIV[@class='issues-list-item clearfix'])[100]
```

How do I loop through these xpath and assert for my text?

I tried the below method after referring few articles and it really did not help.

```
private static WebElement element = null;
    private static List<WebElement> elements = null;

public WebElement test() throws Exception {
    elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//DIV[@class='issues-list-item clearfix'])[1]"));
    for (WebElement element : elements) {

        List<WebElement> TE = element.findElements(By.xpath("(//DIV[@class='issues-list-item clearfix'])[1]"));


        if (TE.size() > 0) {

            String myText = TE.get(0).getText();
            if (myText.contains("High")) {
                return element;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more efficient way to do this is to add your check for "High" to the locator. That way you don't have to loop through all the elements to find only the ones you want. Your locator does all that work for you and more quickly. There's also a lot less code.

```
public List<WebElement> test() throws Exception {
     return driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//DIV[@class='issues-list-item clearfix'][contains(.,'High')])"));
}
```

There are a number of ways you can verify that the desired element is found. One way would be to use a TestNG `Assert` like

```
Assert.assertTrue(test().size() > 0, "Verify an element containing 'High' was found.");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
public List<WebElement> test() throws Exception {
        List<WebElement> TE  = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
         elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//DIV[@class='issues-list-item clearfix'])"));
            for (WebElement element : elements) {
                if(element.getText().contains("High")) {
                       TE.add(element);
                }
            }
            return TE;
    }
```

Note that  , it will return a list web element which contains `High` as text.

Comment: But I need to check all the elements for the text "high" and fail the test if "high" is not found

Comment: so you should return a list of web element.

Comment: Thanks. But it throws a bunch of errors. Incompatible type for `return list`. Cannot resolve method for `contains`. And valiable already define in scope for `element`

Comment: Updated the whole code , This error because we did not use getText Cannot resolve method for contains

Comment: Just a clarification, how does this fail if the xpath doesn't have the text?

Comment: See after calling this method , you have to check for each web element (extract the text) , if it does not contain High text you can make it fail.

Answer (score 0):

`//DIV[@class='issues-list-item clearfix'])[1]` your query is wrong. The [1] at the end means that it will select oinly teh first item from all the items matching the query before, aka you will only compare against the first one. The second query you won't need, neitehr the if checking for size (optionally before the for loop)

Comment: Should I add a wildcard in the place of `[1]` ? How do I assert?